# Aspose.Words delete Nodes in a Bookmark

Tags: nodes, bookmarks, aspose

I have a C# .Net web app using MVC3. I am using Aspose.Words to create a document.  I have a source Document where I find a certain bookmark, then want to remove all the data in that bookmark and replace it with the document I just created.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Bookmark.Text = "" to remove all the data from the bookmark and then use the code snippet given in the '[insert a Word document into another Word document](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Insert+a+Document+into+another+Document)' article to insert document at the bookmark.